# Find $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{4x^{3}-6x^{2}+8x-3}{(x^{2}-x+1)^2}dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

Find  $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{4x^{3}-6x^{2}+8x-3}{(x^{2}-x+1)^2}dx$. I obtained that it is equal to             $\int_{0}^{1} 2\frac{(x^2-x+1)'}{(x^{2}-x+1)^{n-1}}+\frac{(x^{2}-x+1)'}{(x^{2}-x+1)^{n}}dt$. I have problems with the interval of integration because, for $f(x)=x^{2}-x+1$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(0)=1$ and therefore the whole would be $\int_{1}^{1} 2\frac{1}{t^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{t^{n}}dt=0$ and I feel I make a mistake by these changes of integration edges.

Comment: The integral is $0$. This is not a mistake, seeing as $4x^3-6x^2+8x-3$ and $x^2-x+1$ are symmetric about the line $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{4x^3-6x^2+8x-3}{(x^2-x+1)^2}=\frac{2(2x-1)(x^2-x+1)+2x-1}{(x^2-x+1)^2}$$

If$$f(x)=\frac{4x^3-6x^2+8x-3}{(x^2-x+1)^2}$$
then
$$f(1-x)=-f(x)$$

So,answer is clearly ZERO

Comment: Moreover, $${4x^3-6x^2+8x-3\over(x^2-x+1)^2} = {2(2x-1)\over x^2-x+1} + {2x-1\over(x^2-x+1)^2},$$ which this result is obtained via partial fraction decomposition. At this point, the integration is completed via simple $u$-substitution.

Comment: Using $u=x-\frac{1}{2}$ leading to $\frac{16u(5+4u^2)}{(3+4u^2)^2}$ also shows the symmetry $f(-u)=-f(u)$ nicely.

Answer (score 0):

HInt:

One idea:

$$\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2-x+1}\right)}{dx}=\dfrac{(2ax+b)(x^2-x+1)+(ax^2+bx+c)(2x-1)}{(x^2-x+1)^2}$$

Simplify the numerator & compare with $4x^3-6x^2+8x-3$